# How to clear the Terminal Console in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, console, command-line-interface

I am creating a RPG CLI Game with JavaScript and Node.js. I have multiple pages (menu to choose options from, the actual fight...) and I need that every time a page changes everything on the console dissapears so that it always starts at the top of the console.

I need [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCEPK.png) every time I execute the script or choose one of the options on the menu, I need that it always starts at the top of the console.

My code so far:

```js
// Imports
import readline from "readline"

import start from "./menu/start.js"
import load from "./menu/load.js"
import exit from "./menu/exit.js"

// Run function
const run = (args) => {
  const pause = (ms = 500) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms))

  async function welcomeMenu() {
    console.log(`
    +-----------------------------+
    |          Welcome !          |
    +-----------------------------+
    `)

    await pause()

    console.log(`
    1. Start game 
    2. Load game 
    3. Exit ❌
    `)

    await pause()

    // Taking user input
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout,
    })

    rl.question("Your choice (1-3): ", (input) => {
      if (input == 1) {
        start()
        rl.close()
      } else if (input == 2) {
        load()
        rl.close()
      } else if (input == 3) {
        exit()
        rl.close()
      } else {
        rl.question("Your choice (1-3): ", input)
      }
    })
  }

  welcomeMenu()
}

export default run
```

I just need help with clearing the console.

I tried with `console.clear();` but it didn't work.

Comment: Hello, try this library maybe...
https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-clear

Comment: I had to change it from CJS to ESM and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `console-clear` library from `npm`: npmjs.com/package/console-clear

In your Terminal, do `npm install --save console-clear`.
Then, seeing as you use ESM, you'll need to do: `import clear from "console-clear"`.

Then just call it where you want to clear the console: `clear()` or `clear(true)`
Hope I helped